# Spring WebSocket Controller not returning anything

Tags: spring, websocket, postman

I have a problem with with Spring WebSocket, I can successfully connect to the websocket via ws://localhost:port/ws, but I am not able to send or receive anything via STOMP commands(I mean I can send, but I don't know if anything happens)

The WebSocketConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic"); 
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app"); 
    }
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS(); 
    }
}
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SignalingController {
    @MessageMapping("/offer/sendOffer")
    @SendTo("/topic/offer")
    public String sendOffer(String offer){
        // Process the offer and send a response
        return "Received offer: " + offer;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/receive/receiveOffer")
    @SendTo("/topic/answer")
    public String sendAnswer(String answer) {
        // Process the answer and send a response
        return "Received answer: " + answer;
    }
}
```

I tried to test the endpoint with Postman, from which I send the following request:

```
SEND
destination:/app/offer/sendOffer
content-type:text/plain

Test message!
^@
```

I see that is sending this request, but nothing is ever coming back (an ACK or something):
[Postman Websocket sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asQ07.png)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: The Spring boot code is good, but the approaches of testing it were  faulty.

Ok, so after many, many attempts to solve this, I have finally found a way.

First of all, I was trying to connect and send request from an Android application, but before that I tried to test the endpoint with Postman WebSocket(which I abandoned).

Secondly, I tried testing in on Android with OkHTTP3 which didn't work (for whatever reason the STOMP messages were not parsed by the Spring back-end).

Finally, I have come across `org.java_websocket` which worked flawless, I have just sent the STOMP requests as text from the `WebSocketClient.class` and the Spring finally started to route the messages to the controller.

Comment: can you please the code